# Kotlin with Spring Boot 2.1 WebMvcTest - missing beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, kotlin

Here's kind of what I have:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@ActiveProfiles("unit-test")
@WithUserDetails
@WebMvcTest(MyController::class)
class MyControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    lateinit var service: MyService

    @Autowired
    lateinit var mvc: MockMvc
```

But I keep getting exceptions similar to:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type
```

and every time I add in a dependency, such as by:

```
    @MockBean
    lateinit var anotherBean: AnotherBean
```

another missing bean is thrown (kind of endless).

Is there a proper solution for this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

Just add annotation `@SpringBootTest`, from the [spring guides](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/):

> The @SpringBootTest annotation tells Spring Boot to go and look for a main configuration class (one with @SpringBootApplication for instance), and use that to start a Spring application context. You can run this test in your IDE or on the command line (mvn test or gradle test) and it should pass.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your test class with just following two annotations

```
@WebMvcTest(secure = false)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [YourClass::class])
```

**secure = false** is to disable the Spring security configuration.